# PyQT5 Python 3.3 Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, pyqt5

I am new to python and I have an issue running PyQT5 for my Python 3.3 on PyCharm.
I have read several posts about it, some speaking about doing a build which I am not sure to get.
Here is what I have done :

Downloaded and run the .exe found [here](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download5).

Installing normally, the same way as my Pillow for instance (which is running with my Pycharm).

aaaand, that's its.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

==     from PyQt5.QtCore import *
ImportError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtCore'
```

When I setup the module in PyCharm it simply didn't find it. So is the .exe found on the official PyQT5 dead ?

Thanks
Bloby

Comment: Please format your code properly!

Comment: 1. Did PyQt5 install to the approximately same location as pillow? (`import PIL;print(PIL.__file__)`) 2. Can you `import PyQT5`? 3. What is in the site-package folder of your Python installation? 3. Do you have several Python versions installed and this is installed to the wrong version? 4. Have you checked out the side bar on the right? For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19207645/pycharm-3-0-fails-to-find-pyqt5?rq=1

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I have been thrown on something else in the meantime...

Comment: 1:Same location : C:\Python33
2:What do you mean by import PyQT5 ?
3:Not sure where is this site-package folder ? I just provide C:\Python33 for the installation that's all I know.
4:Which side bare, where?
...not sure to follow the exemple
As I said I am new with python, used to maxscript where we are not bothered for simply installing modules... 
Though I did instal Pillow without any problems at all and I can see I am not the only one having problem with this QT module, so it must not be entierly my noobyness, what is it happening ?

Comment: Your question is missing fundamental inputs: \n How did you install Python ? \n Did you set your interpreter correctly ? (In pycharm preferences). You can now install PyQt5 with pip or conda.

Answer (score 0):

I also met the same problem recently, maybe you also install PyQt5 by pip？
It seems that the after using pip, I can import the PyQt5 but not any packages of it, so I have to download the old version with an [installer](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt5/PyQt-5.6/).

Then Pycharm can runs without error.